# Is there a way to replace the headerText by the first value of my dataTable in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want my table headers to have the first value of my dataTable.

I know I can change the value of the headerText but for my project I need the header to change according to the values being output.

So from the picture I want 'col1' to be replace by 'jour', 'col2' by 'lundi', 'col3' by 'mardi', etc

```
<p:dataTable resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true" stripedRows="true" size="large" id="a" var="test"
        value="#{testMB1.testlist}" style="padding:20px;" rows="15" paginator="true"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords} records"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="3,5,10,15,25, 50, 100, 250, 500" rowKey="#{test.id}" scrollable="true" update="mainForm:a"
        frozenRows="1">

        <f:facet name="header">

            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                <p:inputText filterBy="#{test.id}" id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('test').filter()" placeholder="Enter keyword"
                    filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:200px;height:25px;align:right;" />
            </p:outputPanel>

        </f:facet>

        <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{test.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.id}" />

        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col1" sortBy="#{test.col1}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col1}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col1}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col2" sortBy="#{test.col2}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col2}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col2}" />
        </p:column>


        <p:column headerText="col3" sortBy="#{test.col3}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col3}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col3}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col4" sortBy="#{test.col4}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col4}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col4}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col5" sortBy="#{test.col5}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col5}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col5}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col6" sortBy="#{test.col6}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col6}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col6}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col7" sortBy="#{test.col7}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col7}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col7}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col8" sortBy="#{test.col8}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col8}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col8}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col9" sortBy="#{test.col9}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col9}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col9}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="col10" sortBy="#{test.col10}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{test.col10}"
            onkeyup="PF('test').filter()">
            <h:outputText value="#{test.col10}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
```

[My dataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZFMS.png)

Comment: Have a look at https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/datatable?id=dynamic-columns

Comment: how about make a method to return the first element of testlist?

Answer (score 0):

Replace all **headerText** with the code below (according to your mapping object). In the bean, don't forget to verify your list against null, in order not to get a NullPointerException.

```
<p:column headerText="#{testMB1.testlist.get(0).id}">
```

Technically speaking a better approach will be to create in the bean a final list, with the columns headers, and call it in the *headerText*.

If the headers are dynamic, you can use [dynamic columns](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/datatable?id=dynamic-columns), as suggested by [Jasper de Vries](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880619/jasper-de-vries)